# Splitting polygons with multiple lines

Tags: shapely

I work in an Architecture Analytics firm where all our internal representation of floorplans is based on shapely. We have some open spaces (typically kitchen/living room, but also office space) that we need to split  into different functional spaces.

Whenever this split relies on one single line, `shapely.ops.split` does the job, but whenever we have inner disconnected walls (a "floating kitchen" or a fireplace) and we need to draw multiple split lines, this function stops working because each split line does not completely isolate two areas (you can "go around"), and the split function only takes one split line at a time.

Is there a way to provide either multiple lines or a split line made of multiple segments?